# Missing Artifact, Could not resolve dependencies, was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I was trying to add a new dependency ([Easy-Rules](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.jeasy/easy-rules/4.1.0/overview)) to my project:

but the dependency tag is underlined in red:
[image]

```
Missing artifact org.jeasy:easy-rules:jar:4.1.0
```

and if I try to run a maven clean install

```
Failed to execute goal on project architecture-utils: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.paulmarcelinbejan:architecture-utils:jar:1.0.0: org.jeasy:easy-rules:jar:4.1.0 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Why is this happening?
easy-rules can be easily found at [repo.maven.apache.org](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jeasy/easy-rules/4.1.0/)

This is only happening with this dependency.

for example if I add another dependency from maven central repository ([msgpack](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.msgpack/msgpack-core/0.9.3)), it is perfectly working.
[image]

and the jar file is correctly downloaded into local repository.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.paulmarcelinbejan</groupId>
        <artifactId>architecture</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>architecture-utils</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <easyrules.version>4.1.0</easyrules.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paulmarcelinbejan</groupId>
            <artifactId>architecture-constants</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paulmarcelinbejan</groupId>
            <artifactId>architecture-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jeasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>easy-rules</artifactId>
            <version>${easyrules.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>${user.home}/Develop/Personal/maven/repository</localRepository>
  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
  <offline>false</offline>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the files on [Maven Central](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jeasy/easy-rules/4.1.0/), you can see that there is no JAR. The artifact only consists of a pom-file and its hash and signature. `easy-rules` is just the parent project including configuration for its modules.

But if you want to use a (non-pom)-dependency, you need to use an artifact that actually contains a JAR. In your case, this could be [easy-rules-core](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jeasy/easy-rules-core/4.1.0/):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jeasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>easy-rules-core</artifactId>
    <version>${easyrules.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This is also included in the [`Use with Maven`-section](https://github.com/j-easy/easy-rules/wiki/getting-started#use-with-maven) of the [wiki](https://github.com/j-easy/easy-rules/wiki) of the [easy-rules GitHub repository](https://github.com/j-easy/easy-rules).